# MSG_WAITALL doesn't block reading on mac os x

Tags: c, macos, sockets

In documentation of `recv()` function it is written:

MSG_WAITALL

> This flag requests that the operation block until the full
>   request is satisfied.  However, the call may still return less data
>   than requested if a signal is caught, an error or disconnect occurs,
>   or the next data to be received is of a different type than that
>   returned.  This flag has no effect for datagram sockets.

Ok, so it blocks until the full request is satisfied. And in my case I read data in blocking mode to 4KB buffer via `recv()` with `MSG_WAITALL` flag. I know for sure (because of the protocol) that incoming data size is less than 4KB (it is about several hundred bytes), but this call doesn't block, it returns immediately and return value is of course not 4KB (it is about several hundred bytes as it was expected). So what is the point of using `MSG_WAITALL` then? If there is no such available data it returns immediately. In which cases it's necessary to use this flag? Explain me please.

I was testing it on mac os x (TCP).

Comment: It will keep waiting if the sender doesn't close the socket.

Comment: But it doesn't. It doesn't block, it doesn't wait, it just returns all available bytes and that's it.

Comment: Can you post code that demonstrates the problem? We'll need to see the sending and receiving code.

Comment: I can't send you sending code (I'm writing only client code), but the client code is pretty obvious: `ssize_t bytesRead = recv(handle, buffer, buffSize, MSG_WAITALL);`, where `buffSize = 4096` and incoming data size is about just couple oh hundred bytes.

Comment: And it doesn't wait at all.

Comment: Have you tried using `tcpdump` to confirm that the server isn't sending a `FIN` segment after the data?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem (I'm also on OS X). I created a simple client that connects to port 5000 and calls `recv(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1, MSG_WAITALL)`. I started a server using `nc -l 5000`, connected to it with the client program, and started typing into the `nc` window. The client didn't return from its `recv()` call until I typed Ctl-d to send EOF and close the connection.